# Multi horizontal alignment in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, boxes

I would like to realize an alignment like the following:

```
formulaformula1
formulaformulaformula2
           formula3
           formula4
```

So I would like `formulaformula1` and `formulaformulaformula2` to be left aligned, while `formula3` and `formula4` should be left aligned with a specific position in `formulaformulaformula2`.

Also I want to frame it with `\fbox` and put the box in the center.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want this in a displaymath format `\[...\]`, then you might just as well insert the equation in an `array` since it allows for easy bordering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \begin{array}{|l|}
    \hline
    a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2=b_2y^2-b_1y-b_0 \\
    c_3z^3\times c_4z^4\times c_5z^5\times c_6z^6\geq a+b+c+d+e \\
    \phantom{c_3z^3\times c_4z^4\times{}}c_5z^5-9pq+b\ell\alpha h \\
    \phantom{c_3z^3\times c_4z^4\times{}}E=mc^2 \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation with alignment as specific location relative to other components]

The goal here is to use `\phantom{<stuff>}` to duplicate `<stuff>` that you want to use as your alignment tool, but not typeset.

Answer (score 2):

- For multi-line formulas with alignment, [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) environments such as `align` are useful. For example, `alignat*` could be used for equations with multiple alignment places. These environments are appropriate for aligning at relation signs such as equal signs, because of consistent spacing around the relation signs.
- For boxing equations, the [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package is useful. It offers amsmath support and various customizations.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{alignat*=2}
    &ax + by + c + {}&&x = 0 \\
    &ab = c &\\
    &&&x+y=z
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

The first two equations are left aligned, the third equation `x` is aligned with the `x` in the first equation. Alignment at equal signs is not even used yet.

[image: aligned multiline formula with box]

Comment: but the spacing of `c+x` of the first equation is pretty bad. Isn't it a weakness of the alignat environment?

Comment: @pluton: it can be easily fixed by inserting an empty word such as `c + {}&&x`: so the `+` gets spacing as a relation sign, I'll edit above. It's not a weakness of alignat. With alignat just be aware of the intention of typesetting in `rl` columns.

Comment: What if the width of the second line(ab=c) is larger than the one of the first line? I want them to be left-justified...