# Question regarding a mathmode definition layout

Tags: math-mode

I have been trying to get

```
S0    = 0
Si+1  =   { .... }
        U { ........}
        U { ... }
```

definition layout in LaTeX, but have been unsuccessful for hours.

My main problem is that the unions have to be aligned differently than the `=`.

I hope there is anyone that can help me.

Comment: Hi codd, welcome to tex exchange! I inserted the code snippet for you using the `{}`. I also removed the thanks- it seems strange, but it helps to keep the forum in a 'Question and Answer' format :) Have you tried the various environments from the `amsmath` package? It seems your problem could be solved using one of `align`, `aligned`, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is another case where (as an exception to the general rule) putting the relation symbol *before* the `&` can help:

```
\begin{align}
S_{0}={}  & 0\\
\begin{split}
S_{i+1}={}& \mathbin{\hphantom{\cup}}\{...\}\\
          & \cup\{...\}\\
          & \cup\{...\}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

If you don't need to number the formulas, you can omit the `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}` and change `align` into `align*`.

The reason why this is needed is to ensure correct spacing after the `\cup` symbols.

[image]

Comment: I like the combined `align`and `split`. Also, less code clutter.

Comment: does the OP want the `S`s aligned?  if so, the following will do it (it's a kludge): `S_{0\hphantom{+i}}`

Comment: `\mathbin` was new to me, so I searched and found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/what-is-the-difference-between-mathbin-vs-mathrel I think it might be useful to others reading the answers given here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks! I did want that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used `amsmath`'s `split` environment and a phantom for the missing *U* in the second equation:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,fleqn]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     S_0 = & 0 \\
     S_{i+1} = & \phantom{U} \left\{ \ldots \right\}\\
     & U \left\{ \ldots \right\}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can leave out the subscripts if you wish.

I just noticed that this is a possible duplicate of [Multi horizontal alignment in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/multi-horizontal-alignment-in-mathmode)

---

Updated - after applying the recommendations from the comments, here's my second take:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,fleqn]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     S_{0\phantom{+1}} & = 0 \\
     S_{i+1} & = \phantom{\cup} \left\{ \ldots \right\}\\
     & \mathrel{\phantom{=}} \cup \left\{ \ldots \right\}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note: first the separator than the relation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50445/about-alignment-of-mathematics-formulas/50458#50458

Comment: I'd recommend moving the alignment character to the left of the equal, adding the appropriate `\phantom` to get the `S` terms aligned left as desired by the OP, and using an appropriate symbol for union.  In which case I can delete my answer.

Comment: @Peter: Your answer is closer to what the OP wants, isn't it? Anyway, I'll edit my answer according to the recommendations - they're good, after all.

Comment: Christoph, thanks for the (quick) answer. I will upvote your answer, but I am accepting egreg's because I am using it (because I find it more comprehensive).

Comment: two problems: (1) in the first line, the spacing after the `=` is too tight (add an empty group `{}` as a kludge; (2) it's not a U, but a union `\cup`.  better would be to put the `&` before the `=` and adjust spacing manually.  not straightforward.

Comment: I think I was just happy to see an unanswered question I thought I could answer more or less correctly. I was wrong, sort of ;)

Comment: @barbara: Is your comment related to my first or to my second example?

Comment: @Christoph -- to the first example; the second example wasn't there yet when i posted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You current ASCII alignment suggests both "columns" to be `l`eft-aligned. As such, here's an `array` approach to achieve your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{l@{\;}c@{\;}l}
    S_0      &=& 0 \\
    S_{i+1}  &=& \phantom{\cup}\:\{\ldots\} \\
             & & \cup\:\{\ldots\} \\
             & & \cup\:\{\ldots\}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Instead of using `U` for set union, use `\cup`. The spacing adjustments (using `\;` and `\:` corrects any problems introduced by `array` due to column spacing.

You'll notice that the vertical alignment is slightly different (tighter) to that of the other solutions using `align` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). To obtain a similar alignment, use `\\[\jot]` for line endings rather than just `\\`.